# Why TestRestTemplate allow unauthenticated resquest in SpringBoot IT tests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, integration-testing

In my springBoot (RELEASE 1.5.20) app, Basic authentication is enabled. 
I created full IT test with the following code

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "securedIT")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MYtestIT{
@LocalServerPort
     private int port;

   private String getRootUrl() {
        return "http://localhost:" + port;
   }

   @Autowired
   private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testAdmincachWitheWrongAuthentication() {
        String baseUri = getRootUrl() + CONTEXT_ROOT;
         HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(null,  new HttpHeaders());
         URI url = URI.create(baseUri + "/ref/cache/task");

       ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, entity, String.class);
       //ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.withBasicAuth("user", "myPwd").exchange(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, entity, String.class);

     assertEquals(ReferenceWSIT.MSG_WRON_STATUS,401, response.getStatusCode().value());
    }
}
```

And in the App the configuration is like this :

```
@Configuration
public class GlobalWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends 
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("ref/v1/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("ref/cache/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }   
}
```

When I run the Application, authentication filter works perfectly, the problem occurs when I run the Junit integration test.
If I call  restTemplate.withBasicAuth() the test fail or success correctly depending on good or bad credential put.
But if If directly call restTemplate without BasicAuth, all request are allowed (so my test assertion fail).

As an IT test with my full configuration I would expect that the authentication was mandatory why isn't it the case ?

Comment: How have you configured basic authentication on the server side? It sounds like it's only rejecting requests with incorrect credentials and allowing anonymous requests to succeed.

Comment: Do you require authorization for the URI in question? Or does it allow anonymous access?

Comment: I added the configuration example. the resquest in my test should be denied if no credential is added; but it is denied only when I add bad credential, if no credential is inserted during the test, the request is alowed

Comment: @Andy Wilkinson  do you think it's an issue of TestRestTemplate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT] my first solution was wrong, the correct configuration is :

```
@Configuration
public class GlobalWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends 
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().disable()
                //following will disable cookie session to force the browser to Authenticate on each request      
               .sessionManagement()
               .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
               .and()
               .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/ref/cache/**")
               .authenticated().and().httpBasic()
               .and()
               .addFilterAfter(new HmacSecurityFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
               ;
    }   
}
```

First error : antMatcher must begin with a "/" : `"/ref/cache/**"` instead of  `"ref/cache/**"`

Secondly in my second filter (HmacSecurityFilter) I check any request (préviously `.antMatchers("ref/v1/**").permitAll()` ) and I do a custom code to avoid to check the authenticated uri  (/ref/cache/**) .

Comment: be aware your `anyRequest` will take precedence over the `ref/cache/**` if it ever changes. Order matters for configuring your security matchers

Comment: Yes Finnally I realised that now all my request ask for basic authentication even those that contains "ref/v1/...." while I put ".permitAll()" for these requests. How can I manage to allow them now ?

Comment: I completly change the answer. Now it seems to work correctly in both case real and  Unit test